# NSMutableDictionary Sorted Keys and Objects did not Creating

Tags: objective-c, sorting, object, key, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array for users, I want create a contact list.

> I'm sorting objects and keys alphabetically.

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[contactListDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *objects = [contactListDictionary objectsForKeys:sortedKeys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
```

> After this, I can initialize dictionary again with sorted keys and
>   objects.

```
contactListDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:sortedKeys];
```

But it did not sorting keys and objects. They are mixing in NSMutableDictionary, what can I do for this situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything about this, that is, not in the way you are now trying to.
The NSDictionary class does not allow you to tell it in what order to store its keys; that's just not the way it is implemented.
But you already found out that you can get the keys, in the desired order, in an array. There should be no need for the dictionary itself to be ordered, its purpose is to give you a fast lookup mechanimsm, and it does. If you want, for example, to display the keys in order, simply create a (temporary) array created the way you already now how to.